# Can't collect data from dataset/dataframe in Spark 2.0.1; get ClassCastException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some json data that are key value pairs with ints as the keys and a lists of ints as the values.  I want to read this data into a map and then broadcast it so it can be used by another RDD for quick lookup.

I have code that worked on a 1.6.1 spark cluster that is in a data center, but the same code won't work in a 2.0.1 spark cluster in AWS. The 1.6.1 code that works:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
sc.broadcast(sqlContext.read.schema(mySchema).json(myPath).map(r => (r.getInt(0), r.getAs[WrappedArray[Int]].toArray)).collectAsMap)
```

I for 2.0.1 I have tried:

```
val myData = sqlContext.read.schema(mySchema).json(myPath).map(r => (r.getInt(0), r.getSeq[Int].toArray))
```

This gets me what I want at this point:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Int, Array[Int])] = [_1: int, _2: array<int>]
```

But then when I do:

```
sc.broadcast(myData.rdd.collectAsMap)
```

I get:

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

Does anyone know how I can do this in 2.0.1?  It is a very simple thing I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance,

Robin

Comment: Hey, I too posted the same question just now.. Help needed in case you find one.....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233215/unable-to-read-and-later-query-text-file-in-apache-spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my problem was with spark shell in 2.0.1.  The code I posted works fine if I use the existing sc and sqlContext that is part of the spark session that the shell creates.  If I call stop and create a new session with a custom config, I will get the strange error above.  I don't like this as I want to change the spark.driver.maxResultSize.

Anyway, the lesson is: if you are testing code using spark shell, use the existing session or it may not work.

Comment: You should be able to stop a session and create a new one. Could it be a race condition of some sorts? Do you start the new session right after stopping the old one?